# Soft Question: Are sigma fields, fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, probability-theory, soft-question

I'm sorry if this is a foolish question but:
**Is a $\sigma$-field** (of sets) a field (in the sense of algebra) if we only consider *finite* intersections and finite unions?

Comment: How many idempotent elements ($x = x^2$) can a field have?

Comment: At least 2 (1 and 0)...

Comment: Yes. And can you find an upper bound on the number?

Comment: Im thinking 3 (-1,0,1)

Comment: $-1$ is not idempotent. Consider that if $x^2 = x$ then $x^2 - x = 0$.

Comment: $(-1)^2 = 1$, and $1 = -1$ only in characteristic $2$. A field always has exactly two idempotents. So the only $\sigma$-algebra(s) that is a (are) field(s) under $\cap$ as product (and symmetric difference as addition) is the trivial $\{\varnothing,X\}$ for nonempty $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The operation $\cap$ does not permit inverses. Indeed, if $E$ is the identity, then $E\cap\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ so $E=\mathbb{R}$. Now, if every element has an inverse with respect to $\cap$ we should find $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $[0,1]\cap A=\mathbb{R}$. There is no such $A$.

**EDIT:** It is not even a ring because the other operation $\cup$ also does not permit inverses. Indeed, if $I$ is the identity then $I\cup\emptyset=\emptyset$ so $I=\emptyset$. But there is no $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $[0,1]\cup A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the detailed and straightforwardly precise answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider symmetric difference over $ \mathbb{R}$ with $\emptyset$ as the identity.

- $A \triangle  \emptyset = A$
- $A \triangle A^c = \emptyset$

So it is a group over symmetric difference, but what is the other operation for a field?

If you use symmetric difference and intersection you get a ring.  Can we get it to be a field?